# Wild card filtering

Tags: javascript

I am filtering on the cached query result to see if it has the search value.

```
 return this.cachedResults.filter(f => f.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
```

This works great if the `searchvalue` is exactly same as the  `f.name`. I want to filter even if it has the partial value. Like a wild card filtering. How can I do that here?

Comment: Also this is a javascript question, there is nothing particular to angular or typescript in this question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The check expression in `filter` will return `true` if any part of `f.name` contains the string `this.searchValue`.

Comment: Can you please provide a scenario where it's not working?

Comment: @Igor is right, this should return on partial matches as well as long as the sequence of characters is present.

Comment: Unrelated to this question but you could improve it by using `.includes(...)` instead of `indexOf(...) !== -1` and increase performance on larger collections by caching the result of `this.searchValue.toLowerCase()` in a variable, since it's resulting value will always be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing will match partially as well in case when `f.name` includes whole of `searchValue` doesn't matter at what position.

What you might also want is, it should match even when `searchValue` includes whole of `f.name` and not just the other way around.

```
return this.cachedResults.filter(f => {
  return f.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
    || this.searchValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(f.name.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
}
```

---

Also consider checking out [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: That makes sense, the code is a bit unreadable though in the name of terseness. I wonder if this is what OP means.

Comment: I made minimalistic change to the existing code. Of course it can be written better.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use regexp (below support for `?` and `*` wildcards)

```js
let cachedResults = ['abcdef', 'abc', 'xyz', 'adcf', 'abefg' ];
let wild = 'a?c*';

let re = new RegExp('^'+wild.replace(/\*/g,'.*').replace(/\?/g,'.')+'$');
let result = cachedResults.filter( x => re.test(x.toLowerCase()) );

console.log(result);
```